# How enable localization with xwiki framework ?

Tags: javascript, java, xwiki

How enable localization with [xwiki](http://rendering.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome?inputsyntax=docbook%2F4.4&outputsyntax=docbook) framework  ?, can you provide me with an example?, i need to change the localization of an user from my application but i don't know how to enable localization with Xwiki

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somehow vague and it's not clear what part of XWiki you are referring to.

XWiki (http://www.xwiki.org) is a web application that supports internationalization at the UI level, configurable from administration (i.e. setting the available languages and then being able to see or edit translated versions of pages). See for more details: http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/UserGuide/Features/I18N

XWiki is also a web development platform containing a Localization Module (http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Localization/) handling the localization related tasks, including offering a script service for explicitly using the localization module inside in-page scripts (see http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Localization/Scripting/)

For an overview on how to user Localization when developing your XWiki Application, you might want to check out this tutorial: https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/Tutorials/InternationalizingApplications/

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'am talking about xwiki wysiwyg editor which is integrated with [eXo platform](https://www.exoplatform.com) .
So after changing the language from the platform eXo : how change the wysiwyg language (the menu bar labels....).

Comment: I am not sure what the eXo platform implies. Your question was about XWiki so I guess you need to make sure that your XWiki instance has enabled multiple languages or the language your want under Administration > Localization and then, when on a page and when editing the translation in a particular language, the WYSIWYG editor should also display it's UI in the same language, granted that a translation of the WYSIWYG UI exists for that language. Said differently, you don't change the language of the WYSIWYG editor, but it uses the current language that you use for the current document.